Keeping a laptop very secure from hacking- Can you use a laptop without a harddrive booted from a linux USB?

Assuming a hacking, say in the top few percent of hacks, that keeps returning, how can you keep your laptop and phone clean?  What are the vectors, possible entry points, etc.? Again, way more than a usual hacking.

Can you remove a hard drive and run a laptop from a USB with Linux Mint?  (I've run DBAN and wiped the hard drive clean and ran the laptop from a USB before.)


The questions are me trying to maintain a virus/hacking free phone and laptop. The rest of the post is just adding more detail.
I'd really love some help. I got hacked years ago and I haven't been able to keep my phone and laptop clean since. I've had numerous techs tell me this is a high level hacking, very intense. There would be reasons someone might hack me, it's not useful to go into.
I now use public computers that go into "freeze" mode and when they're turned off they start clean, with no files or software added. I can access my email and use an old USB and the virus doesn't seem to get on those machines.
I've bought new laptops and new phones, and gotten them cleaned. I stay on mainstream sites. I'm not making a lot of money and historically, just the new devices haven't solved the problem. I'm looking into addressing the challenge fully.
The virus patterns are devices get hot, battery drains fast, key logger signs of very long lag time from hitting key to seeing a letter, after a while the keyboard no longer functions and I need an external keyboard (this goes away and the keyboard works when I DBAN and wipe the hard drive), ghost windows with prompt boxes appear, updates can take 2-3 hours easily, even for the phone. And I've gone to do a system restore, timeshift, the cursor moved by itself and wouldn't let me do the timeshift. The laptop closed out, wouldn't run for a while, when it started the old timeshifts had been erased. Yes, this happened.
For background, my friends suggested running Linux years ago. I was over my head and didn't know to turn the firewall on (Now I know). The hackers had full control of the machine. The hacking started with an email that had the name of a trusted mentor who knew where I was staying and she mentioned this in the email, (and most people didn't know I was there).  I clicked on the link, a website with the "Shark Tank" TV show came up, and on that show one of the people had just been hacked. Obviously, the link was not from the mentor but a fake email address. The hackers then made an Amazon purchase with my account. I changed all accounts immediately.Unfortunately, they might have gotten some personal documents, IDs and such.
The virus comes back on a cleaned or new phone after logging into gmail (which I know longer do).
I get a new phone or get it cleaned and get texts every day from people I don't know, all generic, "Want to play pool? We're a recruiter, Hello, etc. etc."  If I accidentally click on a text, not a link, which can happen after months of the texts, the virus comes back.
This is having a big impact on my life and work.  It's taking a lot of time and energy.  My work is very important to me.
Again, my best understanding from what I've read and gotten from a chat group is to flash the BIOS, replace the hard drive (or if I can leave it out and just work from the USB, which is fine).
I'll also get a new phone and a new email. And all new USBs. I'll run VirusTotal on any files I introduce onto the BIOS flashed laptop from the cloud.  (I've done all this before, except not the new email.)
I would really appreciate some suggestions. Thank you.

None of the symptoms in your "virus patterns" paragraph indicate a hacking. Yes, you can run most Live Linux distros without a drive installed in the computer. If you're getting spammy text messages, talk to your carrier about getting a new phone number, that's the solution to that. Tapping a text message on a phone doesn't install a virus. We cannot describe every possible attack vector and so the questions you are asking on this post are not applicable to this site. I strongly suggest, for your own sake, and you consider this issue may be better solved by a doctor of some sort.

Most of the things that occurred are described as objectively as possible.  These things do happen.  E.g. "Pegasus is a spyware... to be covertly and remotely installed on mobile phones... governments around the world have routinely used the spyware to surveil journalists, lawyers, political dissidents, and human rights activists.  As of March 2023, Pegasus operators were able to remotely install the spyware using a zero-click exploit."
I know people who protested the Vietnam war who were tracked by the government.
Thank you for the Linux without a drive installed, that was helpful.

That should have been your only question... You always could install and run Linux OS desktop from any USB external drive. The thing is they're very slow and prone to corruption (flash) and only barely acceptable with a decent USB3.x SSD (if compared to a typical internal installation running in a NVMe drive).

(I agree with the comments that it is unlikely your system has been hacked).  To answer your question -
It is almost certainly possible to use a laptop without a harddrive booted from a Linux USB however this is likely to be no more secure - and probably less secure - then a system with a hard drive that has been set up with security in mind.   This is because modern systems have a mechanism to verify the integrity of the booting process and to only allow access to your system if the important parts in the boot process has not been tampered with.  (This is a combination of using Secure Boot, the boot loader and Full Disk Encryption).   When you use USB most of this goes out the window.
Most phones work on a similar process making it very difficult to compromise your phone at a fundamental level (because they implement the whole secure boot process above Strongly - to the point it is difficult to fully access the systems) - although installing random software can allow a partial compromise of your phone.   If the data is worth less then 500k to a TLA you probably don't need to worry about any non-ancient cellphone being fundamentally hacked.  The US$500k figure is what it costs to use Pegasus to compromise a cellphone at that level).  If your data is worth more then US$500k, get an expert to look at it.    Also consider getting a Google Pixel phone with GrapheneOS
To comment on some of the details in your post -
It is possible that some of the things you describe could be indicative of a hacked system, but they don't really add up to that conclusion -

If you are the target of "high level" hacking, the hackers are professionals and will be taking all reasonable steps to make this invisible.  Things like long lag times, battery drain etc are MUCH more likely to be low level hacking where your server is being co-opted to mine bitcoin, participate in a DoS or similar - ie low hanging fruit.   This kind of activity is trivial for any decent AV scanner to pick up, and its easy for someone who knows what they are looking for to diagnose.

Keyboard not functioning and requiring an external keyboard is a hardware fault.  Period.   This is not a hacking issue.  Indeed it is easier for a hacker to hack an external keyboard then the one you have built into your laptop (because they can modify the hardware easily/add dongles).

Updates taking a long time - this is normal.    Part of the code-bloated world we live in.

Linux is only more secure if you know how to use it properly, and because it has less market share on the desktop.

A virus can't come onto a new phone just by logging in to GMAIL.  You would need to do something like run an executable to be compromised.  This is even more true on a phone.  Of-course, if you are running an application on your phone which is bad, and you get a new phone and google installs the new application on that phone - well, thats different.

Fake emails do not indicate a compromise of your computer.  It is trivial to fake email addresses.   There are mitigations to this - like using a combination of SPF, DKIM and DMARC and having them tightly set up.  If you are using an "@gmail.com" account, forget it.   Google is all things to all people, it can't be locked down because it has a 'soft fail' SPF record.


One thing which you have not mentioned.  If your systems are compromised and new systems keep getting compromised as well (which I suspect is unlikely, but lets run with it) - you did not mention your router.   Routers are often hacked.  If the hacked router then hands out bad DNS servers, your new systems are already a lot more vulnerable then they would otherwise be.   If you do get new systems - make sure they are behind a new router, and seperate to your old systems.
